# sync do sequelize não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, react, express.js, sequelize-js

salve comunidade! estou tentando usar o sequelize, onde no meu server.js coloquei o comando:

```
const db = require("./app/models");
db.sequelize.sync();
```

porém ao rodar o node ser.js apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me salva?

Comment: A mensagem diz que o `db.sequelize` não foi definido. Dá uma olhada nas configurações do teu db, como ele foi inicializado...

Comment: Dá uma olhada [na documentação](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/) e compara com o teu código, para ver os motivos de não estar definido...

Comment: olhei na documentação e consegui resolver. 

vou postar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo usado, o sequelize estava na versão 5.21 o meu está na versão 6.20.

Com isso na declaração o meu precisava de chaves:

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
```

Enquanto no exemplo que estava olhando não tinha.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).